# How to handle buttonclicked event of DDDW?

Tags: button, powerbuilder, datawindow

**Situation**:
I have a button in my DDDW and i want to capture buttonclicked event.

**Problem**:
when i click on the button in DDDW the buttonclicked event of DW Control is not fired and ItemChanged event is fired for DW control.

**Question**:
How do i capture buttonclicked event for the button in DDDW? Or is there any other way i can delete a row from DDDW when delete button is clicked for a particular row?

[image]

PowerBuilder 12.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PB help, a DataWindowChild has no events :|

But, that doesn't mean we still can't hook into it via the DW control's `itemchanged` event.  **Note:** this is a hack, and underwent some very-limited testing. But, it demonstrates a point, I guess.

Here's what I did:

- Created a DataWindow with the `code` and `name` columns, and a computed field (for the red X) named `delete_button`
- Created another DataWindow and painted that DW as a DDDW on there, named `profession`
- In my window control's `open` event, I got the DDDW from the DW and stuck it in an instance variable:
  `dw_1.GetChild("profession", REF idwc_profession)`
- Then, coded the `itemchanged` event for the DW control:

```
    // dw_1::itemchanged
    //
    //  - DDDW is named "profession"
    IF dwo.Name = "profession" THEN
        IF IsValid(idwc_profession) THEN
            string ls_clickedobject
            // Get the DataWindowCHILD object where the pointer was clicked:
            ls_clickedobject = idwc_profession.GetObjectAtPointer()

            IF IsNull(ls_clickedObject) OR (ls_clickedobject = "") THEN RETURN

            // Return from GetChild is <column name>~t<row number>; let's get
            // the position of the tab character so we can parse it
            long ll_tabPos
            ll_tabPos = Pos(ls_clickedObject, "~t")

            IF ll_tabPos > 0 THEN
                string ls_clickedDddwColumn

                ls_clickedDddwColumn = Trim(Left(ls_clickedObject, ll_tabPos - 1))
                // Check to see if we've clicked on the computed field with the delete button
                IF Lower(ls_clickedDddwColumn) = "delete_button" THEN
                    long ll_clickedDddwRow
                    // grab the row we want to delete
                    ll_clickedDddwRow = Long(Trim(Right(ls_clickedObject, Len(ls_clickedObject) - ll_tabPos)))

                    IF ll_clickedDddwRow > 0 THEN
                        // delete the row from the DDDW
                        idwc_profession.DeleteRow(ll_clickedDddwRow)

                        SetNull(data) // reset our data
                    END IF
                END IF
            END IF
        END IF
    END IF

RETURN
```

Also note that you may have to play around with the return value from `itemchanged` to get it to do what you want.  And, if you want to automatically dropdown the DDDW again after the deletion happens, you'd might be able to use the `Send()` method to do so (I don't know the right "number" for that, though).

Comment: Creative. As far as that windows message to drop a combo box down, I think it's Const CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = &H14F

Comment: Nice idea. anyway, if profession name is misspelled then new code is already given  and two codes exist for the same profession. Selection from DDDW is the time when most user finds that mistake. so there is delete button. Actually, delete button in DDDW makes no sense to me more than that. for example a tray full of different candies is presented to me and i keep throwing those i dont like and then pick the one i like is sure kind of stupid thing Sybase did not do. I cannot think of any other situation where delete button is important in DDDW.

Comment: Itemchanged cannot fire where data value is same as column value.